# When powers of a matrix are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a question in my math material I don't know how to solve. It states that $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, I need to determine whether the set $\{I, A, A^2\}$ is linearly independent.

I think this set is linearly independent, but I am not really know how to prove this. Anyone would like to help me about this? Thanks.

Comment: For $A=I$ it is certainly not independent. What do you know about $A$?

Comment: I only know A is a random 2*2 matrix.So I just suppose A= {a,b; c,d}

Comment: What does  Cayley-Hamilton say  again?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg it said that A^2 = tr(A)A- det(A)I. What should I know from this ?

Comment: @KellyAnn : That $\exists a,b,c\in\mathbb{K}, a A^2 + b A + c I = 0$ with $(a,b,c)\not= (0,0,0)$

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg's comment is the whole point of the question. What does the characteristic polynomial of a $2 \times 2$ matrix look like?

Comment: @copper.hat i think the characteristic is det(A-xI)=0

Comment: $\det (xI-A) = x^2+p_1 x + p_0$. A matrix satisfies its own characteristic polynomial, what does this say about linear independence?

Answer (score 3):

$A\in M_2(\mathbb{K})$

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\chi_A=X^2 -\operatorname{tr}(A)X+ \det(A)I_2$

By Cayley-Hamilton, $\chi_A(A)=0_2$, that is $A^2 -\operatorname{tr}(A)A+ \det(A)I_2=0_2$

So $\exists (a,b,c)\in\mathbb{K}^3, aA^2+bA+cI_2=0_2$ namely $(a,b,c)=(1, -\operatorname{tr}(A),\det(A) )$ where $a=1\not= 0$

Which means that $\left\{I_2,A,A^2\right\}$ is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Considering $A=I_2$ we see that $-2I+A+A^2=0$ where $\mathbb R$ is taken as the corresponding field of scalars. Consequently, $\left\{I, A, A^2\right\}$ is **not** linearly independent.

Comment: Please note the point by @xavierm02, that $\left\{I_2,A,A^2\right\}$ is linearly dependent *for every $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$*.

Comment: aah...forgot to recall Cayley-Hamilton.